# Excel Do While Find

Tags: vba, excel

Below is my code that uses .Find function in excel to find the location where dodCell appears in sheet2 and to add reeCell to column 18 in sheet2 from sheet1. This is suppose to loop based on how many times it finds strSearch in rRange.

But, it currently it is only running once and stops, I think there is a mistake in my "Do While Loop" but I can't seen to fix it.

Any thoughts?

So after fixing some errors that were pointed out in my code I have revised the sub. I think I have addressed the Loop issue, but know the program is running once and is freezing excel and then I need to restart Excel. I think I have created an infinite loop but don't know how to fix it any ideas?

```
    Sub addnumber()
    'used to add ree value to Dod projects
    Dim sSht As Worksheet, dSht As Worksheet
    Dim lastrow As Integer
    Dim firstAddress As String
    Dim strSearch As String
    Dim ReeCell As Range, dodCell As Range, aRange As Range, rRange As Range, aaRange As Range
    Dim hold1Cell As Range, holdCell As Range, lastCell As Range
    Set sSht = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set dSht = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Set rRange = sSht.Columns(18)
    Set aRange = sSht.Columns(1)
    Set aaRange = dSht.Columns(1)
    lastrow = sSht.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    strSearch = "2*"
```

```
    Set dodCell = rRange.Find(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    'If something dodCell holds a value then enter loop
    If Not dodCell Is Nothing Then
        'Set lastCell to dodCell
        firstAddress = dodCell.Address
        Do
                    'Set ReeCell to the value of the Ree number
                    Set ReeCell = dodCell.Offset(0, -17)
                    'Set holdCell to the Cell that holds that Dod number in "Sheet2"
                    Set holdCell = aaRange.Find(What:=dodCell, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
                    'Set hold1Cell to the location that the Ree Value should be
                    Set hold1Cell = holdCell.Offset(0, 9)
                    'Give hold1Cell the Ree # from ReeCell
                    hold1Cell = ReeCell.Value
                    Set dodCell = rRange.FindNext(dodCell)

        Loop While Not dodCell Is Nothing And dodCell.Address <> firstAddress
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196143.aspx i dont think you need "After:="

Comment: The finding part works fine and it performs all the  required iterations. Nonetheless I think that you haven't set the loop/condition to accomplish what you want. Can you explain what you want to do exactly in the loop? If the string is not found, the loop is exited, but what you want to do otherwise (every time an occurrence is found)?

Comment: In my "Do While loop" I have it looping until the current address of the found keyword matches the address of the previous matched address. This would mean that no other matches exist in that column

Comment: I know that. Also it exits if no match is found. But what is the difference between finding one match or 10? Your code would just go over and over until exiting without doing anything (storing a value/changing a variable). So... what you want to do there?

Comment: After a new test, I realised that it works (more or less) as expected and thus I am not sure about what you want. Your statement "... This would mean that no other matches exist in that column" is wrong; it will always iterate through this cell again. Please, let me know what you want to do exactly, and I will perform the corresponding modifications: just confirming that there is one match? Counting the number of matches? What to do every time a new match (different than the one above) is found?

Comment: I have posted an answer correcting your code to determine whether there is just one match or more than one.

Answer (score 0):

I think your Do While loop may be working correctly.  It looks like your problem is that your code that alters the cell contents is not within the loop as well.  You set dodCell, change the value of that based on another find, and then you loop to find the next dodCell, and get the address of it (`Set dodCell = rRange.FindNext`, etc.), but then just exit the loop and then the Sub.

Try moving some of your other code into the loop and see if you get expected results.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a modified version of your code determining whether there is a single occurrence of the target string or not (when `justOne` is `True`):

```
Dim beyondFirst As Boolean
Dim justOne As Boolean
Do While ExitLoop = False
    Set dodCell = rRange.FindNext(After:=dodCell)
    If Not dodCell Is Nothing Then
        If Not beyondFirst And dodCell.Address = lastCell.Address Then
            justOne = True
            Exit Do
        End If
    Else
        ExitLoop = True
    End If
    beyondFirst = True
Loop
```

As you defined it, this loop will iterate through all the cells where the target string is present. As far as you are using `After`, the first cell found will not be iterated until the last moment; this is the base for my correction: if the given `Address` matches the one of the original cell, it would mean that there is just one match ONLY if it happens in the first iteration.

Answer (score 0):

APrough is correct that the do loop does not contain all the parts you want in it.

It is not clear to me what you want the do loop to do, but as it stands the do loop does nothing but end automatically during its first loop: either when `dodCell.Address = lastCell.Address` (Exit Do) or at the start of the next loop, since all other instances of dodCell set `ExitLoop = True`.

To get the loop to do anything (other than end automatically) you need to include other code in it. For example your Set statements, just above the start of the Do Loop, seem like items you may intend to iterate and may want to move into the do loop.

**Additional comments**

Your new code does appear to move the appropriate items into the do Loop. However, it looks to me like nesting `.Find` methods, as you have done, resets the register for active `.Find` instances.

That means that when you initiat the `holdCell = dSht.Find` the register for `dodCell` is reset. On `.FindNext` the same `dodCell` is found and the `firstAddress` will match the `dodCell`, ending hte do loop after only one iteration.

The solution I came up with to allow the do loop to run through the entire search range involves the use of a `For Each` statement that loops through the`holdCell` values and finds matches to the current `dodCell`.  There are more efficient ways of doing this, but the following code should work as a start. It will be slow if there are very many rows: it loops through every row on Sheet2 for every dodCell value found.

Here's my code:

```
Sub AddNumber()

'used to add ree value to Dod projects

    'create variables
        Dim wSht1 As Worksheet
        Dim wSht2 As Worksheet

        Dim sFirstrDodCell As String
        Dim sSearch As String

        Dim rDodRange As Range
        Dim rHoldRange As Range
        Dim rDodCell As Range
        Dim rHoldCell As Range

    'establish initial variable values
        Set wSht1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set wSht2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")

        wSht1.Activate
        Set rDodRange = wSht1.Range("R1", Range("R" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        wSht2.Activate
        Set rHoldRange = wSht2.Range("A1", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

        sSearch = "2*"

    'find rDodCell values
        Set rDodCell = rDodRange.Find(What:=sSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        'If something rDodCell holds a value then enter loop to find Sheet2 matches
            If Not rDodCell Is Nothing Then

                'Set sFirstrDodCell to first rDodCell
                    sFirstrDodCell = rDodCell.Address

                'Apply rDodCell values on Sheet2
                    Do
                            For Each rHoldCell In rHoldRange
                                If rHoldCell.Value = rDodCell.Value Then
                                    rHoldCell.Offset(0, 9).Value = rDodCell.Offset(0, -17)
                                End If
                            Next
                            Set rDodCell = rDodRange.FindNext(rDodCell)
                    Loop While Not rDodCell Is Nothing And rDodCell.Address <> sFirstrDodCell
            End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I Karl I have added some revised code in an edit, I'm still having difficulty make my code loop more then once.